# Нахождение фундаментальной системы циклов в графе

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int n, m, x, y;
vector<vector<int>> g;
vector<bool> used;
vector<int> stack_;
vector<int> index;
vector<pair<int,int>> tree_edge(100);
vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> FSC(10);
void DFS(int v);
void Check(int v);
void Save(int i,int j,int nZ);
 void DFS(int v)
 {
    
    used[v] = true;  
    stack_.push_back(v);
    for (int i = 1; i < g[v].size(); ++i)
    {
        Check(v);
        int to = g[v][i];
        if (!used[to]) 
             DFS(to);
    }
}

void Check(int v) {
    static int curr = 0;
    static int nZ= 0;
    if (!used[v]) {
        stack_.clear();
        if (tree_edge[v].first == NULL)
            tree_edge[v].first = v;
        else if (tree_edge[v].second == NULL)
            tree_edge[v].second = v;
        DFS(v);
    }
    else {
        pair<int,int> fpair=tree_edge[curr];
        for (int i = curr; i < tree_edge.size();i++) {
            if (tree_edge[i].first == fpair.second&& tree_edge[i].second==fpair.first) {
                nZ++;
                Save(curr,i,nZ);
                i++;
                curr = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Save(int i, int j,int nZ) {
    static int num = 0;
    for (i; i < j; i++) {
        FSC[i].push_back(tree_edge[i]);
        cout << tree_edge[i].first<<" "<< tree_edge[i].second<<endl;
    }


}
int main() 
{   
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    ifstream in("input1.txt");
    in >> n;
    in >> m;
    used.resize(n);
    g.resize(n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        in >> x >> y;
        index.push_back(x);
        index.push_back(y);//     
        g[x].push_back(y);
        g[y].push_back(x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        tree_edge.push_back(make_pair(NULL, NULL));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < used.size(); i++)
        used[i] = false;  

            DFS(index[0]); 

        
    cout <<"Количество независимых циклов: "<< m-n<< endl;
    in.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Граф в файле:

5 //кол-во вершин

7 //кол-во ребер

1 2 // дуги

1 3

1 4

1 5

2 3

2 4

2 5

Пытаюсь найти ФСР графа(количество всех независимых циклов). У меня не получается. Помогите дописать прогу. Должно выводить 4 независимых цикла.

Comment: (1) У вас массовые выходы за границы массивов, поскольку во входном файле узлы нумеруются с единицы, в `g[x]` предполагается нумерация с нуля (поскольку вектор в с++ индексируется с нуля). Аналогичная ошибка при обращении к `used`и другим массивам. (2) Вам все-таки нужна фундаментальная система или только ее размер?

Comment: Возможно, я недопонимаю, но часто замечаю проблему отсутствия единой и однозначной терминологии в теории графов. Потому стоит внимательнее относится к формулировкам при постановке задач. Вы пишите `ФСР`, что является **фундаментальной системой разрезов.** "Фундаментальная система циклов" и "количество всех независимых циклов" - это одно и то же? Почему Вы ожидаете 4 цикла? Что означает их независимость?

Comment: да я уже решил проблему,закрыть вопрос нельзя ведь.а ФСР это система разрезов,да.перепутал.но ее мне тоже надо делать. ФСЦ это количество всех независимых циклов,да.а че не так,что ли?4 цикла я ожидаю,потому что пример такой.из книги брал,где все это описывается.независимые циклы это циклы,которые отличаются хотя бы на одно ребро